# Yii localization: Currency code?

Tags: yii, localization, currency

Yii Framework provides a simple way to find the currency symbol for any given currency code (USD/EUR/JPY...), for example:

```
Yii::app()->locale->getCurrencySymbol('USD');
```

But how do we find the currency code which corresponds to the locale in use?

Comment: you whant to get currency code of that, from which opened website?

Answer (score 1):

There is no relation set in Yii between the locales and currency symbols. You need to do your own mapping if you need such relation.